# Seach for string and email string when not found

Tags: grep

I want to search a file for two strings, and make it email me THE STRING it was searching for, only when it is not found. (e.g when it doesn't find the string 'FIRST_SEARCH_STRING', I want it to email me 'FIRST_SEARCH_STRING).

I can make it email the strings when found using:

```
grep -Ew 'FIRST_SEARCH_STRING|SECOND_SEARCH_STRING'|sendmail "subject" my@email.com
```

Comment: It's not clear what action needs to be taken when the first string is found? Should the subject line in the email contain '2nd str notfound` and vice-versa? Also what if none of the strings is found then what should be the subject line?

Comment: i would like to have the string that was NOT found emailed to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ! grep -q 'pattern' /path/to/file; then
    mail -s 'pattern not found in file' user@example.com
else
    do_stuff
fi
```

Comment: perhaps a loop like `for search in FIRST_SEARCH_STRING SECOND_SEARCH_STRING ...`, so that they can get an email with the (non)-matching word?